# PHP: Replace number in a string with its word equivalent

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a function that converts numbers into words called `NumberToWords`.
Then I have a sentence like this

$str = "There are 3 cats and 5 dogs".

`NumberToWords(3)` will read three
`NumberToWords(5)` will read five

So, what I want to achieve is for the final sentence to be

"There are three cats and five dogs".

I can use `preg_replace("/[0-9]/", NumberToWords(), $str)` but how can I tell the NumberToWords() what is the value that it should convert to number?

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @anubhava comment I ended up with this which worked fine

```
$str = "There are 3 cats and 5 dogs".

function getMatchedValue($matches) {
  return NumberToWords($matches[0]);
}

preg_replace_callback("/[0-9]{1,20}/", 'getMatchedValue', $str);
```